# Which documentation generator is used for lodash.com

Tags: node.js, documentation-generation, lodash

Any ideas what is the documentation generator used by [lodash.com](http://lodash.com)? I have been looking around into their documentation and using google and cannot find anything. I'd like to use a similar documentation style on a small project of mine

Comment: I'd like to know this, too. I couldn't find anything in their GitHub projects and there's nothing revealing in the page's source. Perhaps it's a custom job (shrug).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Lodash is using [docdown](https://github.com/jdalton/docdown) for docs generation. I ran into the same question and fortunately I found the answer in their [github](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/817) [issues](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/1258).